# LineEdit doesn't show exception from another class, crashes when returning value

Tags: exception, pyqt, return-value, qlineedit

I have two modules; one is a frequency parser that should return a value in Hz otherwise through some exceptions depending on different mistakes in the user input.

Here is the code (ModuleParse.py):

```
import re

FrequencyTypes = {
    "T": 1E12,
    "THz": 1E12,
    'G': 1E9,
    'GHz': 1E9,
    "M": 1E6,
    "MHz": 1E6,
    "K": 1E3,
    "KHz": 1E3
}


class FreqParse:
    def __init__(self, Input, mode):
        self.Input = Input
        self.mode = mode
        self.UserInput = self.Input.replace(" ", "")
        self.Str = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', self.UserInput)
        self.Num = re.findall('[0-9]+', self.UserInput)
        if self.mode == "Frequency":
            self.handling = self.FrequencyHandling

    def FrequencyHandling(self):
        FreqNum = self.Num
        FreqStr = self.Str

        try:
            if len(FreqNum) != 1:
                raise TypeError('Frequency input should be in the format of "number" or "number+unit"; '
                                'for example: 64000000000, 64E9, 64GHz, or 64G')
            else:
                if len(FreqStr) >= 2:
                    raise TypeError('Frequency input should be in the format of "number" or "number+unit"; '
                                    'for example: 64000000000, 64E9, 64GHz, or 64G')
                elif len(FreqStr) == 0:
                    VALUE = float(FreqNum[0])
                    print(VALUE, " Hz")
                    #return VALUE
                else:
                    try:
                        if FreqStr[0] in FrequencyTypes:
                            VALUE = float(FreqNum[0])*FrequencyTypes.get(FreqStr[0])
                            print(VALUE, " Hz")
                            #return VALUE
                        else:
                            raise KeyError("Unit wasn't found in the FrequencyTypes dictionary; available units are: "
                                           "T (THz), G (GHz), M (MHz), K (KHz)")
                    except KeyError as error1:
                        print("Error> ", error1)
                # return VALUE
        except TypeError as error:
            print("Error> Wrong input: ", error)
```

Second module is a gui code (ModuleGUI.py). In the "Frequency" field, when user inserts a value, it checks the input using "ModuleParse.py"; if it is correct, it should return a value, otherwise shows the exception/error in the "plainTextEdit_1" window.

here is the code for "ModuleGUI.py":

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import ModuleParse


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(738, 234)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 150, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.lineEdit_1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 80, 121, 20))
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.lineEdit_1.editingFinished.connect(self.UserInputSampleRate)
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 80, 80, 13))
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 110, 121, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 110, 80, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.plainTextEdit_1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_1.setEnabled(False)
        self.plainTextEdit_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 441, 81))
        self.plainTextEdit_1.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 738, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "64e9"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Frequency (Hz)"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Next field"))


    def UserInputSampleRate(self):
        if not self.lineEdit_1.text():
            color_format = self.plainTextEdit_1.currentCharFormat()
            color_format.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
            self.plainTextEdit_1.setCurrentCharFormat(color_format)
            self.plainTextEdit_1.insertPlainText("Sample Rate > Enter a value \n")
        else:
            FrequencyParseOutput = ModuleParse.FreqParse(self.lineEdit_1.text(), "Frequency")
            self.plainTextEdit_1.setPlainText("{} \n".format(FrequencyParseOutput.FrequencyHandling()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Unfortunately, it is not working as I expected; first, "plainTextEdit_1" doesn't show the Exception message defined in "ModuleParse.py". Second, if I uncomment "return VALUE" in the "ModuleParse.py", "ModuleGUI.py" will crash when user inserts the correct value.

Note: I decided to use "editingFinished" for "lineEdit_1" as a signal method because if I use other methods, when I am making any changes in the "lineEdit_1", it will call "ModuleParse.py" instantly and it is not desirable.

Comment: You're never returning the text for the exception, you're just printing it. You should replace that with something like `return "Error> Wrong input: " + str(error)`. Note that I don't get any issue when uncommenting `return VALUE` as long as the value is just numerical, but I do if literals exist, and that's because you're doing the same mistake of just *printing* the key error before `return VALUE`. Finally, the regex search is inconsistent with your logic: you say that you allow "64E9", but `re.findall('[0-9]+')` returns *two* numbers for that, and `len(FreqNum) != 1` prevents that case.

Comment: Frankly, I find all that nested try/raise/except usage quite unnecessary: catching/managing exceptions makes sense when they are fundamental for the flow of a specific logic implementation so that you can eventually "fix" the values or ignore certain cases, but you're mainly using it for validation. So, just do that: return an error string if there are no numbers or the literal part is not recognized, and eventually add a try/except when actually processing the value. You'll probably need a more stable and reliable regex syntax in any case, using groups for numbers, units and exponential.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your answer. It was absolutely helpful and solved my problems. Also, thanks for the point regarding "64E9". I didn't notice it. Can you please advise how I can solve this issue? I must say I got a headache when I was trying to find an optimum solution to seperate letter from numbers using regex, in my case. Still, I couldn't find a proper solution

Comment: @musicamante while I was writing my first response, I missed your 2nd comment. Thanks for that. Regarding your suggestion about try/except, I am processing value in two if statements (the first one is when len(FreqStr) == 0 and the 2nd one is when FreqStr[0] in FrequencyTypes).  Not sure if I get it right but if I do such a thing, I might end up with two try/except statement similar to the one I have right now

Comment: Well, you need to dig more into regexes for these purposes, you cannot just rely on basic searches via `findall`. You practically have 3 groups, with the following requirements: 1. at least one digit; 2. letter "E" followed by at least one digit; 3. any of "T", "G", "M", "K", *eventually* followed by "Hz". One possible solution could be to compile this regex: `r'(\d+)(?:(E\d+)?([TGMK]?(?:Hz))?)'`; that should be fine for basic situations and would return exactly three groups if the `match()` properly returns a match: you'll always get the number, then you'll eventually get the exponential->

Comment: ->if `E<number>` exists after the value, or the unit suffix, if any. Then it's just a matter of getting the number of the exponential if it exists, and capture the multiplier from the first letter of the unit: if it's "H" it means there's no multiplier. On a separated matter: you should **not** edit pyuic generated files, as it's a bad practice and always discouraged. Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @Rex The UI should be designed to make it simple and intuitive for the user to enter the values without even allowing the possibility of making mistakes. This can be done very easily with a QSpinBox for the numbers, and a QComboBox for the frequency type. Parsing text from a QLineEdit and reporting errors is the wrong approach, and provides a very poor UX; the user should never be forced to guess the correct input format in that way. If the UI is desgned correctly, there should be no need for a parsing module or any error handling.

Comment: @musicamante sorry for my slow reply. Thanks a lot for your helps. It is much better now.  Also, thanks for the note to not edit pyuic generated files. I need to learn how to implement it in this way.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your comment on my method. I will take into account your feedback and modify my GUI to be easy to use.